# implementing Static library in New iphone App

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have created a static library libTest.a.

1. i am added that library into my new project.
2. After that i added the header search path and Library search path.
3. And i added -ObjC -all_load in OtherlinkerFlag.

   In Simulator everything works fine... In device i am facing a error  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Test", referenced from:
   How to fix this issue ? Pls help me..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my Mac at hand, so I can't confirm this, but the settings you changed initially to link to the library might need to be changed again for different builds/target (release/debug, device/simulator).